# Вытащить класс из коллекции типа абстрактного класса

Tags: java, коллекции

Всем привет !

Каким образом можно вытащить класс из коллекции (на примере)

Имеется абстрактный класс `Игрок`:

```
public Player(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }
```

Имеется класс `Вратарь`

```
public GoalKeeper(String firstName, String lastName, int age, int handling, int aerialAbility) {
        super(firstName, lastName, age);
        this.handling = handling;
        this.aerialAbility = aerialAbility;
    }
```

Позже я создаю объект и помещаю его в коллекцию типа `Игрок` (абстрактный класс)

```
players = new ArrayList<Player>();

        players.add(new GoalKeeper("Олег", "Газманов", 11, 44, 35));
```

Каким образом я могу из этой коллекции вытащить данные класса `Вратарь` ?
Спасибо !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Необходимо проверить и привести тип:

```
Player player = players.get(0); //или другой индекс
if (player instanceof GoalKeeper) {
  GoalKeeper goalKeeper = (GoalKeeper) player;
  //...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо человеческое, большое !)

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `instanceof`, но, на мой взгляд, лучше добавить перечисление с возможными позициями игроков:

```
enum Position {
  GK, DC, FW // etc
}

abstract class Player {
  abstract Position getPosition();
  ...
}

class GoalKeeper {
  @Override
  Position getPosition() {
    return Position.GK;
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: А дальше как использовать этот Position? Да и нафига он нужен если привязывается жёстко к классу? Тот же instanceof, вид сбоку.

Comment: Использовать также как и `instanceof` - зависит от намерений автора. Преимущество такого подхода: возможность использования перечисления в `switch` и элементах UI-интерфейса (например, в качестве значений для выпадающих списков) + такой подход более соответствует ООП: мы работаем с абстракцией более высокого уровня, а не с проверкой на соотвествие классов. Это мое мнение, если `instanceof` достаточно, то используйте его.